# How can I use the unit mu in an hspace?

Tags: spacing

I tried combining `hspace` with the "math unit" `mu` inside a math environment, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
$\delta \hspace{1mu} f$ 
\end{document}
```

But this leads to the error "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)." I am confused - I thought, in math mode I can (or even should?) use the unit `mu`?

As a workaround, I used `em` in math mode. With `18mu = 1em`, my code is

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
$\delta \hspace{0.0555em} f$ 
\end{document}
```

and compiles fine. But I still wonder - why can't I use `mu`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to use `mu` units you need `\mskip` or `\mkern`.

If you load `amsmath` you have `\mspace`, that's preferable to `\mskip` in the same way `\hspace` is preferable to `\hskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}  

$\delta \mspace{1mu} f$

\end{document}
```

There is a fundamental difference between `\hskip` and `\mskip`: the latter uses the em relative to the symbol font in the current style (so it will be smaller in subscripts, for instance). In view of this there is no conversion formula, unless you want to use `\mathchoice` that, in this case, would be too much business for a small thing.